# How to add a .xml extension to a specific URI using .htaccess

Tags: xml, .htaccess, expressionengine

I have a URL at the moment www.mydomain.com/feed/my_feed/ which writes out an xml document to be read by a third party. The XML document is dynamically generated (I'm using ExpressionEngine).

The third party have requested that it must have a .xml extension to be read.

Any ideas how I could set up a .htaccess rule to only use a .xml file extension for this particular uri?

Most tutorials are concerned with removing file extensions adding file extensions to all urls, which doesn't help a .htaccess noob.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be able to skip the rewrite and just add an additional segment that will be ignored.  www.example.com/feed/my_feed/whatever.xml

Answer (score 0):

So if the URL the third party is using is: `www.mydomain.com/feed/my_feed.xml`

You want to add this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?feed/my_feed.xml$ /feed/my_feed/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble using .htaccess to rewrite the .xml off of a URL before. Frequently when I need to do this I'll just use the Pages module and put `/something/something.xml` as the Pages URI. Then you can point the page at any template you want.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Sorry just seen this and sounds like a good way to do things. In this instance I had some control over the URL structure so found a really simple solution to work around this.

If your template that renders the code is /feed/my_feed/

Then if you add an additional segment to the end regardless of the file extension e.g. /feed/my_feed/feed.xml - Then ExpressionEngine ignores the last segment and will just default to rendering /feed/my_feed/