# wordpress htaccess url: add extension to 1 url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

This is the original url
http://www.mysite.com/product-feed/

and it should be
http://www.mysite.com/product-feed.xml

My Htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?product-feed.xml$ /product-feed/ [L]
```

this doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

If people are going to `http://www.mysite.com/product-feed/`, and they should instead be going to `http://www.mysite.com/product-feed.xml`, then the rule you have is backwards. The syntax of `RewriteRule` (or `Redirect`) is:

```
RewriteRule <the pattern that matches the URL> <what the URL should be>
```

So it should look like:

```
RewriteRule ^product-feed/$ /product-feed.xml [L,R]
```

Comment: I'm new to .htaccess, but not sure why your answer here is opposite: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11546348/3085310 :D

Comment: @Felix: He has done this because, in the case of that question, no redirection is meant to happen. Notice the lack of the `R` flag on your answer. Then check back with the other one, which is an alias, instead of a redirect. If, however, `/product-feed/` is the actual URL that presents the feed to the user, then you need to use the other one. In fact, you can use both.